# Cannot open a virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

When I try to open a virtual machine, I get the error: "The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is permission problems with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing 'modprobe vboxdrv'
as root".

But when I execute 'modprobe vboxdrv', I get "could not insert 'vboxdrv':Required key not available." 
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have `secure boot` enabled in your bios. Check by running

```
 dmesg | grep -i secure
```

It is working as designed, stopping unsigned code being added to the kernel. Disable secure boot to allow the virtualbox kernel module to load.

Comment: It does say I have secure boot enabled. How do I disable it?

Comment: nvm, I figured it out.

Comment: @lukekong If this answer resolves your problem, remember to accept it by clicking the 'tick' mark next to the answer.